# Is there a way in SQL server to apply case statement to multiple columns?

Tags: sql-server, case

I am looking to apply a CASE condition to multiple columns simultaneously. And, if possible, for multiple tables as well. I know it is  possible to replicate the code, but as there are many columns I though there might be a more efficient way.

Example:

```
SELECT
CASE COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4
WHEN 1 THEN 0
WHEN 2 THEN 1
WHEN 3 THEN 2
WHEN 4 THEN 3
WHEN 5 THEN 4
WHEN 6 THEN 5
WHEN 7 THEN 6
WHEN 8 THEN 7
WHEN 99 THEN NULL
END AS COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4
FROM TABLE1
```

And if possible, do the same procedure for TABLE2, TABLE3, etc ...

EDIT: The value in the columns are codes representing the number of days the user is online in each application in a platform. So what I'm intending to do is sum those values to get to the total days online. The value 1 represents 0 days online, 2 represents 1 day online and so on. So I need to change those to the actual number of days.

Thank you!

Comment: what the problem you are trying to solve , explain your problem ,  you might get a better solution here , however asnwert to your question is no , you can't do that

Comment: You could write a function then apply it to each column in turn, but otherwise, I don't know of a way to do that.

Comment: However, this looks like a [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: A `CASE` **expression** (T-SQL does not support `Case` (`Switch`) statements) accepts a boolean expression and returns a scalar value. `CASE COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4` doesn't make any sense as they are 4 scalar values. What are you *really* trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

...multiple columns⇛unpivot⇛one column⇛case result⇛pivot⇛multiple columns...

(better to test/compare performance with multiple case-when-end per column)

```
declare @t table
(
id int identity,
name varchar(1),
col1 int, col2 int, col3 int, col4 int, col5 int, col6 int, col7 int
);

insert into @t(name, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7)
values
('a', 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 99),
('b', 5, 1, 2, 99, 3, 4, 4),
('c', 4, 3, 99, 4, 99, 2, 99),
('d', 2, 5, 5, 1, 2, 99, 3),
('e', null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

select t.*, '<--before:after-->' as before_after, _case.*
from @t as t
outer apply /* <-- change to cross apply..diff...*/
(
    select pvt.*
    from
    (
    --unpivot
    select
        unp.colname,
        --case goes here 
        case unp.col
            when 1 then 10
            when 2 then 22
            when 3 then 33
            when 4 then 40
            when 5 then 56
            when 99 then NULL
            else 0 
        end as col 
    from (select t.*) as ut
    unpivot (col for colname in (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7) /*<--list of columns...*/ )as unp
    ) as u
    pivot (min(u.col) for u.colname in (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7) /*<--...same list of columns*/ ) as pvt
) as _case;
--
```